# perl: can end block be called when program is 'kill'

Tags: perl

```
BEGIN {
    while (1) {
        print "hi\n";
    }
}


END {
    print "end is called\n";
}
```

in shell:

```
kill <pid>
```

OUTPUT:

```
hi
hi
hi
hi
hi
hi
hi
hi
hi
Terminated
```

The end block didnt get called when i killed it via kill or ctrl-c.

Is there something equivalent that will always get called before program exits

Comment: You'd have to put a signal handler in place to handle the signal and do something appropriate.  Calling the end block per se will be tricky; you might need to wrap the contents in a function and call the function from the end block and the signal handler.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ctrl C sends a `SIGINT` to your program. You can 'catch' this with a signal handler by setting the appropriate entry in `%SIG`. I would note - I don't see why you're using `BEGIN` that way. `BEGIN` is a special code block that's called at compile time - at the very first opportunity. That means it's triggered when you run `perl -c` to validate your code, and as such is really a bad idea to set as an infinite loop. See: [`perlmod`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlmod.html#BEGIN%2C-UNITCHECK%2C-CHECK%2C-INIT-and-END)

E.g.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

$SIG{'INT'} = \&handle_kill; 
my $finished = 0; 

sub handle_kill {
     print "Caught a kill signal\n";
     $finished++; 
}


while ( not $finished ) {
    print "Not finished yet\n";
    sleep 1;
}

END {
    print "end is called\n";
}
```

But there's a drawback - some signals you can't trap in this way. See [`perlipc`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlipc.html#Deferred-Signals-%28Safe-Signals%29) for more details.

> Some signals can be neither trapped nor ignored, such as the KILL and STOP (but not the TSTP) signals. Note that ignoring signals makes them disappear. If you only want them blocked temporarily without them getting lost you'll have to use POSIX' sigprocmask.

By default if you send a `kill`, then it'll send a `SIGTERM`. So you may want to override this handler too. However it's typically considered bad to do anything other than exit gracefully with a SIGTERM - it's more acceptable to 'do something' and resume when trapping `SIGHUP` (Hangup) and `SIGINT`.

You should note that Perl does 'safe signals' though - and so some system calls won't be interrupted, perl will wait for it to return before processing the signal. That's because bad things can happen if you abort certain operations (like `close` on a file where you're flushing data might leave it corrupt). Usually that's not a problem, but it's something to be aware of.

Answer (score 4):

put the proper signal handler in your code:

```
$SIG{INT} = sub { die "Caught a sigint $!" };
```

the control-c sends the SIGINT signal to the script, who is catched by this handler